# Почему на последний палиндром выдает false

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пож. почему на последний палиндром выдает false, пробелы убрал.

```js
function palindrom(str) {
   str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'');
   if (str === str.split('').reverse().join('')) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}



console.log(palindrom('raCecar')); // === true;
console.log(palindrom('table')); // === false;
console.log(palindrom('А, роза упала на лапу Азора')); // === true;
```

Comment: Потому что в коде не учитывается запятая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кроме пробелов нужно убрать и остальные не буквы.

В данном случае мешается запятая.

Для этого можно воспользоваться следующим регулярным выражением `/[^a-zа-яё]/g`

```js
function palindrom(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-zа-яё]/g, '');
  if (str === str.split('').reverse().join('')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}



console.log(palindrom('raCecar')); // === true;
console.log(palindrom('table')); // === false;
console.log(palindrom('А, роза упала на лапу Азора')); // === true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g,'');
```

Потому что сейчас не учитывается то, что в строке могут быть и другие символы, помимо пробелов, а `\W` будет учитывать любой символ, кроме буквенного. ([https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Comment: Благодарю!) Помогло! А, есть специализированные сайты, которые помогают получить, сгенерировать юни код?

Comment: Не понял вопроса)

Comment: К примеру вставил свой текст, выделил часть строки и программа сгенерировала подгодящую шифровку

Comment: Кажется сейчас вы сами используете какую-то шифровку.

Comment: Я ничего не понимаю, что вам нужно)